# multiple tab slideToggle in Angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

I have side menu with 5 tabs. I want to do a slide toggle using angularjs. I have the code in jquery. I don't know how to do in angularjs.

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/mdx20uqe/9/)

```js
$('h2').click(function(event) {
  var $this = $(event.target),
    id = $this.attr('id'),
    partialId = id.split('-');

  if ($('#' + id + 't').is(':visible')) {
    $this.parent().children('div').slideUp();
  } else {
    $this.parent().children('div').slideUp();
    $('#' + id + 't').slideToggle();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="stage1">
  <h2 id="location-1">Location</h2>
  <div id="location-1t">grjryjj
  </div>
  <h2 id="jersey-1">JERSEY </h2>
  <div id="jersey-1t" style="display: none;"> ighlgkiuluil
  </div>
  <h2 id="details-1">details</h2>
  <div id="details-1t" style="display: none;">fykyuk
  </div>
</div>
```

This fiddle example is the exact one what i am expecting. But it is in jquery. I want the same thing in angularjs.

I want to open only one tab at a time. If I open one rest everything should close. How can I do this in angularjs.

Comment: You should have to give it a try and if you stuck then ask question on SO

Comment: Why not just use Bootstrap Framework ? Because that's just a dropdown toggle.